# Cause most visited list to re-use existing tabs in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

If I open a link from the Most Visited page, or from the bookmarks list, I would like it to check and see if that URL is already open, and, if it is, to go to that open tab, instead of opening the page again.

What plugin would you recommend that will accomplish this, preferably (but not necessarily) avoiding an over-blown feature-set.

Answer (score 1):

Go into your add-ons and look for deduplicate-tabs.
You will have an icon that displays that you have duplicate tabs. Clicking it will dismiss them.